# setting a regular expression into the emacs header line

Tags: regex, search, emacs, header, lisp

So I'm new to emacs lisp, and I've got a long file with walls of text broken up by dates.  Sometimes I can't see what date I'm reading under without scrolling up and losing my position, and I decided I wanted to be able to see this at all times.

After skim-reading the manuals, borrowing code examples and making a wild stab in the dark, the following worked beautifully:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (setq header-line-format
          '(:eval
                    ;;(setq temp-point point)
            (setq temp-string
              (if (re-search-backward "../../.." nil t nil) (match-string 0) '("no date"))
              )
            ;;(goto-char 'temp-point)
            `(temp-string)
            )
          )
        )
      )
```

There's only one fly in the ointment: re-search-backward moves the point.  I want it to stay put.

First of all, is there a function that can do a regexp search without moving the point and return the match?

Secondly, and whether or not that's true: as you can tell from the commented code I've been trying to work around it by saving the value of point and then resetting the position afterward.  The order of the code is on the assumption that the last element of the list is the one that gets returned.

However that assumption doesn't seem to always hold: as soon as I uncomment the first line (which can actually be anything as long as it's valid code) the header gets set to a blank string instead.

If someone could tell me where I'm going wrong, that would be great.  Also if I've got any bad habits or less-than-efficient ways of solving a problem, please point them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `save-excursion` macro. Wrap it around your search, and it will undo any movement.  To quote the docstring:

> `(save-excursion &rest BODY)`
>
> Save point, mark, and current buffer; execute BODY; restore those things.

So in place of `(re-search-backward "../../.." nil t nil)` you'd put:

```
(save-excursion
  (re-search-backward "../../.." nil t nil))
```

---

As to why uncommenting the first line would change the result, this has to do with the way `:eval` works in mode/header line format specs.  The docstring for `mode-line-format` says that it's `(:eval FORM)` - with just *one* form - and apparently it silently ignores any forms after the first one. (Your intuition is correct: most of the time the last value inside the form is returned, and the behaviour of `:eval` is indeed surprising.)

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks very much.  But while I won't need to make another excursion of my own into emacs LISP again for a while (probably), I am curious as to why uncommenting the top commented line in my code example meant that the `(temp-string) line was no longer the returned value?

Comment: Found the answer: `:eval` only uses the _first_ form, and silently ignores the rest.  See my updated answer.